# What does setBytes' Parameter Index do

Tags: java, sqlite, parameters

I have the following line of code:

```
conn.prepareStatement(SQL).setBytes(1, bos.toByteArray());
```

Where *SQL* is my prepared statement string, and *bos* is my byteArrayOutputStream

I know that parameter 0 in the setBytes is for the **parameterIndex** according to [Oracles Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) which states:

> Sets the designated parameter to the given Java byte value.

*My question is what exactly does that mean? What happens if I switch the 1 with a 2 (or any other number); what functionality does it serve?*

I looked at a few SQLite tutorials and no one I've found mentions what this actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL statement of your prepared statement has place-holders marked with `?`. 
The first parameter of `setBytes` (or any other `setX` method) determines which of these place-holders you are assigning the value to.

1 corresponds with the first `?` in your SQL statement, 2 corresponds with the second `?`, and so on...

For example, if your statement is :

```
    "SELECT X, Y " +
    "FROM TableName " +
    "WHERE Z = ?"
                       );
```

`setBytes(1, bos.toByteArray())` assigns the passed byte array to the first (and only) `?` in the statement. In that example `setBytes(2, bos.toByteArray())` would be an error, since there is only one `?` in the statement.

Comment: Oh, of course; it's the same in MySQL. Thank you! (I will accept the answer in a moment)